# TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Tags: javascript, fetch, promesas

estoy intentando ejecutar varias promesas y de tal manera estoy usando Promise.all de la siguiente forma:

```javascript
var components={};
        var uris={};
        uris.html = chrome.runtime.getURL('src/html/frame.html'); //obtiene una URL
        uris.js = chrome.runtime.getURL('src/js/frame.js'); //obtiene una URL
        uris.css = chrome.runtime.getURL('src/css/frame.css'); //obtiene una URL
        
        console.log(uris);
        
        Promise.all( // aqui ocurre el error
            Object.entries(uris).forEach(([key, uri]) => {
                fetch(uri).then(r => components[key] = r.text());
            })
        ).then(
            results => {
                console.log(components);
            }
        );
```

pero obtengo el siguiente error:

> document.js:101 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

el objetivo es obtener en un objeto con las propiedades: html, js, css los archivos en formato de texto. pero no lo estoy logrando, y no se cual es el error. soy malo en javascript.

Comment: ¿Qué esperas exactamente?  `Promise.all()` recibe como argumento un array de promesas y `Object.entries(uris).forEach` no devuelve nada, de ahí que te diga `undefined is not iterable `. En todo caso la función que más se acerca a lo que buscas es `Object.entries(uris).map()`. Usa `Promise.all(Object.values(uris).map(url => fetch(url)))` y sigue con los `then`.

Comment: el problema es que necesitaba usar las keys para rellenar una variable con indice asociativo y map no recibe el indice solo el valor ...

Comment: igual ya lo he publicado como respuesta, aunque me hubiera gustado hacer una iteración dentro del promise.all y que tambien me ubiera gustado llevarlo a una funcion externa pero no llega hasta haya mi conocimiento ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo para complementar tu respuesta y de cierto modo terminar lo que intentabas hacer utilizando los iterables del array, podrías haber intentado:

```
Promise.all(Object.entries(uris).map(([key, uri]) => fetch(uri)))
  .then((res) => Promise.all(res.map(r => r.text())))
  .then(([html, js, css]) => { console.log(html, js, css) })
```

O bien usando async-await:

```
const getFiles = async (uris) => {
  const peticiones = await Promise.all(Object.entries(uris).map(([key, uri]) => fetch(uri)))
  const [html, js, css] = await Promise.all(peticiones.map(r => r.text()))
  console.log(html, js, css)
}

getFiles(uris)
```

Comment: me queda una duda ... como sabes que el array se va a llenar con los datos correctos ... [html, js, css] a esto Promise.all(peticiones

Comment: otra cosa si coloco console.log(html, js, css) debajo de getFiles(uris); imprimira los datos o saldran pendiente o undefined?

Comment: El orden en que recorras las promesas será el orden en que te devuelva el resultado. Como en tu objeto primero declaraste html, luego js, y luego css, ese es el orden en que map colocará las promesas dentro del Promise.All y por lo tanto, el orden en el que recibiras los resultados. Promise.All respeta el orden de las promesas y te da los resultados de cada una por su posicion especifica.

Comment: Si colocas console.log(html, js, css) debajo de getFiles(uris), te obtendrás undefined. Las variables html, js y css no existen fuera del scope de la función async. Incluso si las haces globales, la peticion fetch tarda bastante, para cuando esten listos los datos el console.log hace rato ya se habrá ejecutado.

Comment: ok entiendo gracias

Comment: lo que si veo extraño es que al imprimir la constante html me devuelve el html de la pagina actual y no la del fetch esta raro...

Comment: Ya eso es problema de la url que le estas pasando por parámetro al `fetch` . La verdad primera vez que veo eso de `chrome.runtime.getURL`. Probablemente ahí esté el problema.

Comment: es programacion de extensiones ... estoy programando con la api de google chrome

Answer (score 1):

el problema esta en que `Promise.all()` debe trabajar con un array de promesas entonces lo lleve de la siguiente forma:

```
var components = {};
        components.html='';
        components.css='';
        components.js='';

        Promise.all([
            fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL('src/html/frame.html')).then(resp => resp.text()).then(resp => components.html = resp),
            fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL('src/css/frame.css')).then(resp => resp.text()).then(resp => components.css = resp),
            fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL('src/js/frame.js')).then(resp => resp.text()).then(resp => components.js = resp)
        ]).then(r => {

            console.log(components);

        });
```

ahora si bien esto soluciona el problema de forma procedural; me hubiera gustado hacerlo orientado a objetos y que una funcion retorne los componentes; en lugar de tener que trabajar dentro del `.then()`

Comment: No existe forma de sacar el resultado fuera del método `then` de una Promesa, a menos que la misma la proceses con `await` dentro de un entorno `async`. Por otro lado, ¿a qué te refieres con *ahora si bien esto soluciona el problema de forma procedural; me hubiera gustado hacerlo orientado a objetos*?

Comment: pues pensaba crear una clase y que esta clase gestionara este tipo de peticiones y regresar los datos pero como dices no se puede sacar del then